# Camera stretched view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use the surface view for showing my customized camera , but view of camera is looking stretched compare to original camera but it was recorded properly.

How can i resolve that problem ?

I use the following code,

```
public class CamcorderView extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    MediaRecorder recorder;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    String outputFile = "/sdcard/greVat.mp4";
    Context c;

    public CamcorderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        c=context;
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        if (recorder != null) {
            try {
                recorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("IllegalStateException", e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    public Surface getSurface()
    {
        return holder.getSurface();
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if(recorder!=null)
        {
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

    public void setOutputFile(String filename)
    {


        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    }
    public String deleteVideoPath(){
        return path;
    }
    public String startRecording()
    {   recorder.setOutputFile(path);

        recorder.start();

        return videoName;
    }

    public String stopRecording()
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder=null;

        return path;
    }
    public void release(){
        recorder.release();
        recorder=null;
    }
    public void init(){
        recorder=new MediaRecorder();
    }
}
```